# Spark Key/Value filter Function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data in a Key Value pairing. I am trying to apply a filter function to the data that looks like:

```
  def filterNum(x: Int) : Boolean = {
    if (decimalArr.contains(x)) return true
    else return false
  }
```

My Spark code that has:

```
val numRDD = columnRDD.filter(x => filterNum(x(0)))
```

but that wont work and when I send in the:

```
val numRDD = columnRDD.filter(x => filterNum(x))
```

I get the error:

```
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, String)
 required: Int
       val numRDD = columnRDD.filter(x => filterNum(x))
```

I also have tried to do other things like changing the inputs to the function

Comment: well that's because x(0) is an Int (the key) and x is a tuple (Int,String) (key,value)

Comment: How do I write the function to take that in? I've tried making the x: Array[String].

Comment: I believe you have your answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `RDD.filter` is passing in the Key-Value Tuple, `(Int, String)`, and filterNum is expecting an `Int`, which is why the first attempt works: `tuple(index)` pulls out the value at that index of the tuple.

You could change your filter function to be

```
def filterNum(x: (Int, String)) : Boolean = {
  if (decimalArr.contains(x._1)) return true
  else return false
}
```

Although, I would personally do a more terse version as the false is baked into the `contains` and you can just use the expression directly:

```
columnRDD.filter(decimalArr.contains(_._1))
```

Or, if you don't like the underscore syntax:

```
columnRDD.filter(x=>decimalArr.contains(x._1))
```

Also, do not use `return` in scala, the last evaluated line is the return automatically

Comment: You could use `productElement(index)`, but that is worse IMO...or you could use pattern matching, but again it would be uglier IMO